# "Let us continue this discussion in chat" comment is missing

Tags: support, bug, automatic-comments

Usually, after a few comments back and forth between two users, we get a message saying:

> **Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to [automatically move this discussion to chat?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396966#)**

..and when clicking the hyperlink, it automatically adds a comment saying:

> Let us continue this discussion in chat

I just did so in the comments under [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61437577/8967612). It redirected me to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212539) but it didn't add that comment. I posted a message in the room, went back, clicked the same link again and I found my message there but still no comment.

**Is this a bug or was this behavior changed at some point?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The post author already previously clicked the link to create a chat room for the discussion, and shortly deleted that comment after.

I think both of you were shown the link around the same time but the other user clicked the link first. Users may create a chat room once per post.

Thankfully moderators can see deleted comments, so I've recreated the link to the room in a new comment.

> [image]